# Create an ISO File Repository or Mirror Repository on Native Windows

Tags: updates, windows-10, repository, iso, localrepository

I have a ubuntu system with a base install where I want to update the OS with the latest package versions, although this system does not have access to the Internet. I could use some direction on two possibilities that I see:

1. How do I create an ISO file of the entire update repository? I understand how to mount already made ISO but what are the step by step instructions to make the actual ISO file of the repository?
2. I have a Windows machine where I could setup a mirror although I cannot load a virtual Ubuntu instance on that machine to create the mirror. The mirror has to be created on the native Windows machine. Everything I read explains how to create a mirror using Ubuntu commands but I have to do it on Windows without access to a Ubuntu virtual machine.

Any help with these approaches are greatly appreciated!

Comment: FYI: An ISO of the whole Ubuntu repository would need to store 1.5TB of data  in size (size of repository as documented here - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mirrors) so that's the amount of data your windows would need to store; plus what the ISO would need; if it were possible (*FYI:  I'm sure it is possible; it's just not worth it for anyone to do it!*)

Comment: In later comments to an answer you reveal that this system is on an enterprise intranet. There's a whole level of IT Department involvement that needs to happen to ensure that the system is kept safe, secure, available, and within your organization requirements. Rather than cobble together an update repository, some enterprises run a mirrored test machine (without data) that CAN upgrade from the internet. Then, after testing and security review and perhaps a rehearsal, the upgrade packages are sneakernetted to the production system.

Answer (score 0):

1. not possible
2. not possible

There is no method of creating an ISO for updates. Updates are determined by checking to newest version against the version your system uses to update and you do not have that compare available from a Windows system.

If it is an offline setup updating is not really needed so maybe you should forget about that? If you have a specific issue you could download the newest packages and dependencies limiting to that specific issue.

Mind also that if you could create a mirror on the Windows machine you would still have an issue updating your Ubuntu machine since you stated you can not have Ubuntu connected to the internet. That would require a connection with the machine you have Windows on and if you can make that connection you can also connect your Ubuntu to the internet.

---

The only way I would see working with the setup you describe (Windows using internet, Ubuntu not capable to connect) is that you download the point release when it arrives. So when 22.04.2, 22.04.3, 22.04.4, 22.04.5 etc are released you download and transfer the ISO to your Ubuntu and then mount that ISO (either as a file or from a DVD/USB). You could then update from the ISO.

I would focus on fixing the problem though and not to try to go through too many hoops to get around that: get internet working on that machine. Either directly or by creating a bridge in Windows.

Comment: Point of clarification. I can VPN into an internal network with the Windows machine and access the Ubuntu server on the Intranet. The government entity that I work for does not allow internal systems (Ubuntu machine) external Internet access. But machines can access one another on the Intranet. So if I could 1) set up a mirror on the Windows machine; 2) VPN into the Intranet with the Windows machine, that would in essence give me a local internal mirror to update from.

Comment: Even if there was an easy way to load packages like net_tools from the deb file manually without dealing with the dependency mess in a manual way. If there were some way to generate a package list of all the dependencies for a primary package and a way to bundle them all up easily so I could do a local package install from deb files - that would help.

Comment: eh "The government entity" then I would assume setting up a repo on a windows machine is also not allowed. You would create a security risk. and again: this is an offline machine so maybe forget about upgrading and only do a reinstall from a point release when it arrives. There is no real need to update an offline system (you will not get newer software anyways)